# Import remote module

Tags: go

I'm new to golang and trying to create and import a remote module

See the file structure here https://github.com/clarkk/go-hutil

Downloading the remote module there is an error

```
# go get github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/hutil
go: github.com/clarkk/go-hutil@v0.0.0-20230816231413-20409caaa685 (matching github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/hutil@upgrade) requires github.com/clarkk/go-hutil@v0.0.0-20230816231413-20409caaa685: parsing go.mod: go.mod:1: usage: module module/path
```

## In the main package where I want to import and use the module

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/hutil"
)

func main(){
    p := hutil.Path()
}
```

The downloaded module doesn't show the version but instead v0.0.0

```
go-hutil@v0.0.0-20230816231413-20409caaa685
```

## update

Have tried to follow best practice and only have one `go.mod` in the root

Fetch module package (Error: package not found)

```
# go get github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/path
go: module github.com/clarkk/go-hutil@upgrade found (v0.0.0-20230816234648-90086d622d8e), but does not contain package github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/path
```

Import and use

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/path"
)

func main(){
    p := path.Path()
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: It's night and I'm a bit tired. Get an error when doing `go get ...`

Comment: Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67448535/how-do-i-create-a-nested-go-module-within-a-repository) with an answer you might find helpful. Basically what you are trying to do is have a module which is not located at the root of its repo - which is possible but sort of non-standard. If you do decide to keep the module in a subdirectory, you can find some info [here](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-version) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; your `go.mod` file should be:

```
module github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/hutil

go 1.21
```

---

##### 1. module directive

Your module directive in [hutil/go.mod](https://github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/blob/37a0cc408f8654215b980da4853498772bf9da4b/hutil/go.mod#L1) is as follows:

```
module github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/hutil v0.0.1
```

The syntax for [module directives](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-module) is defined as follows:

```
ModuleDirective = "module" ( ModulePath | "(" newline ModulePath newline ")" ) newline .
ModulePath      = ident | string .
```

So as you can see the parser will fail because of the  `v0.0.1`.
How to properly version your module is described below.

---

##### 2. go directive

Your go directive in [hutil/go.mod](https://github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/blob/37a0cc408f8654215b980da4853498772bf9da4b/hutil/go.mod#L3) is as follows:

```
go 1.21.0
```

The syntax for [go directives](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-go) is defined as follows:

```
GoDirective = "go" GoVersion newline .
GoVersion   = string | ident .  /* valid release version; see above */
```

Although not as explicit as I would like, based on the examples in the document, it seems that a *"valid release version"* is either:

- `1.N` (a "language version") or
- `1.NrcR` (a "release candidate")

So you should truncate the *patch version* (i.e. `.0`) from your go directive.

---

##### 3. module version

https://go.dev/ref/mod#versions

> Each version starts with the letter `v`, followed by a semantic version. See [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) for details on how versions are formatted, interpreted, and compared.

> Go may access modules in version control systems **using tags**, branches, or revisions that don’t follow these conventions.

https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-version

> Each module version should have a *semantic version **tag*** within the repository that indicates which revision should be checked out for a given version.

So to version your module you can add a semver tag to the repository, e.g.

```
git tag -a v0.0.1 -m "v0.0.1"
git push origin v0.0.1
```

Note that, once your module reaches version 2, your `ModulePath` in the module directive should include a *matching* major version suffix of the form `/vN`.

https://go.dev/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes

> Starting with major version 2, module paths must have a major version suffix like /v2 that matches the major version. For example, if a module has the path example.com/mod at v1.0.0, it must have the path example.com/mod/v2 at version v2.0.0.

> Major version suffixes are not allowed at major versions v0 or v1. There is no need to change the module path between v0 and v1 because v0 versions are unstable and have no compatibility guarantee. Additionally, for most modules, v1 is backwards compatible with the last v0 version; a v1 version acts as a commitment to compatibility, rather than an indication of incompatible changes compared with v0.

Comment: have tried to follow best practice and instead only have a `go.mod` in the root. When I import the package the module is found but not the package

Comment: Have tried to get inspiration from https://github.com/google/go-cmp but doesn't seem to succeed

Comment: @clarkk In [this version](https://github.com/clarkk/go-hutil/tree/a8b79888b0a8cfc40e65bade1dc75c389d273907) the problem is that you've moved the `go.mod` file but kept the full module path (including the subdirectory that does not exist in the repo anymore), by itself this should still work but when you then try to download such a module and/or import packages in such a module that's when the problems will appear.

Comment: @clarkk also note that while it's true that the majority of modules in the wild is located in their repository's root, it is not a requirement. The reference document mentions modules in subdirectories and there are even official [examples of that](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/master:gopls/).